# Terminal asks for password but does not let me enter anything (15.04)

Tags: command-line, permissions, 15.04, steam, administrator

Whenever I try to open steam or some other programs, it opens the terminal and asks for my password, but when I try to enter it, it does not type anything and pressing enter just says sorry, try again. Also, when I try to modify config files for programs it comes up with a 'no permission' error. I am an administrator on my computer. How do I fix this?

Comment: Thats weird. Steam does not ask for password from terminal AFAIK. BTW, when entering the password in command line, it is not displayed, even as asterisks. You are typing it for sure, but it wont display it. So there is nothing wrong with that. Can you post the output of `file ``which steam```

Comment: Sounds fishy.  Apps, particularly steam, shouldn't call terminal and ask password there.  Open a separate terminal window, preferably `xterm` and run  `xprop`  command , and select the fishy window. `xterm` will display info about that terminal. Paste it to paste.ubuntu.com, provide link here. Also, do you have telnet or ssh server enabled on your machine ?  Observe some of the connections with `netstat -tlpan`. Anything unrecognized ? use `whois` or `nslookup` to find out whom ip addresses belong to

Comment: Could you post the output of `file 'which steam'` (Replace the single quotes with backtick ``, the symbol below tilde ~).

Comment: @Kenpachi i think backticks are somewhat depreciated, you can use `file $(which steam)` instead

Answer (score 2):

When at the Terminal and it asks you for a password, it seems that you're not writing, but actually you are.

Try to write your password again and press Enter

Comment: That did not work, but if I hit enter and type it in after that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal doesn't show password while you typing (not even Bullets or Stars)

So when it prompt for password, just type your password blindly, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question - this is normal UNIX behavior. It will not display anything while you type a password. It is "concealed". Trust that it is indeed there, and press Enter when you're finished typing. Since concealing like this is possible by using a simple ANSI escape code (the same method by which we color and bold text in the terminal), it is possible that it was used the a third-party developer as well.

Regarding your second question - just because you're an administrator on the computer doesn't mean you can edit files outside of your home folder right off the bat. This is one of Linux's core security features. Being an administrator means that you can "sudo", that is, work as the system root. You have to outright tell the computer you *want* to work as sudo before you can in any given session, however. That's also for security reasons (and so you don't accidentally mess something up.)

Let's say you want to edit `/etc/foo.conf` (that file doesn't actually exist...I made it up for the example.) You could not just say `gedit /etc/foo.conf`, as that would say "No permission." Instead, you would have to run `sudo gedit /etc/foo.conf` and enter your login password if/when prompted.

Since these are pretty normal things, my guess is that you're new-ish to the terminal. I recommend you read up on the [basics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal). The Terminal is a powerful tool, but it is equally dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: It is not achieved by ANSI escape sequences but by using termios (stty) settings: disable local echo, and don't do remote (applevel) echo either.

Answer (score 0):

Which password are you typing in? Your steam account or your user password on the computer? I imagine it's asking for a sudo command, and typing your steam password then would result »sorry, try again«

Although, I agree with Serg that this sounds fishy. Steam starts terminal but doesn’t ask for my password.